# IdentityServer4 API calling another API

Tags: identityserver4

I have two WebAPI ASP.Net Core `Api1` and `Api2`. `Api2` is just something like centralized database which is being called by `Api1` in a Quartz job (once per hour for example) to get some data to synchronize in `Api1`. The question is how should I use IdentityServer4 to use `Api1` as a client and `Api2` as a protected resource? Should `Api1` be both resource and client? Then which grant type should I use? How to get token by `Api1` and use it to call `Api2`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the client-credentials flow to secure service-to-service communication. This is the flow to use when there is no human user involved.

You define APpi1 as a client with client credentials flow enabled. And Api2 is defined as a ApiResource (with ApiScope as well).

With this flow, Api1 can get its own access token to call Api2. Api2 can then verify the token signature by downloading the JWKS keys.